# Swap index in Maxwell's Tensor multiplication

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, notation

Why in
\begin{align} F_{\kappa\lambda}F_{\kappa\lambda}  = \left( {\partial _\kappa  A_\lambda  \partial _\kappa  A_\lambda   - \partial _\kappa  A_\lambda  \partial _\lambda  A_\kappa   - \partial _\lambda  A_\kappa  \partial _\kappa  A_\lambda   + \partial _\lambda  A_\kappa  \partial _\lambda  A_\kappa  }\right),\end{align}
we can do $k \leftrightarrow \lambda$,  so it turns into
\begin{align}
    F_{\kappa\lambda}F_{\kappa\lambda}  = 2\left(\partial _\kappa  A_\lambda  \partial _\kappa  A_\lambda - \partial _\kappa  A_\lambda  \partial _\lambda  A_\kappa \right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

If we mean Einstein's convention of summing repeated indices, all the indices in the first equation are dummy indices

Answer (score 1):

Was there really any index swapping? Maybe you just used commutative property for multiplication, as in $(\partial_\lambda A_\kappa)\partial_\kappa A_\lambda = \partial_\kappa A_\lambda(\partial_\lambda A_\kappa)$ (I assumed derivative only applies to something immediately on its right). If there's some implicit summing going on, swapping would work as well...

Edit: yes, there was index swapping for the outer terms. It's because in $\sum_{\lambda, \kappa} \partial_\lambda A_\kappa \partial_\lambda A_\kappa $ you can rename $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ to whatever you want, it's a dummy index, such as in: $\sum_{\text{whatever 1}, \text{whatever 2}} \partial _\text{whatever 1} A_\text{whatever 2} \partial _\text{whatever 1}A_\text{whatever 2}$. In particular, you may take $\text{whatever 1} = \kappa$ and $\text{whatever 2} = \lambda$